# MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '') when closing a SQL query. Is it because of the connection?

Tags: mysql-5.7, python

Salut les administrateurs ! I have a question (and an issue) When closing my SQL query in my ETL I get a connection error while it seemed I was able to get connected:

```
    c.execute("""
        UPDATE `{table_name}` 
        SET `{column_name}` = CONCAT('hash_', {expression})
        WHERE {pk_name} IN ({ids})
    """.format(
        table_name=table_name, column_name=column_name, expression=expression, pk_name=pk_name,
        ids=','.join(ids)
    ))

    print('.', end='', flush=True)
```

Indeed, I get:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools>python -m etl.main
2021-06-29 10:59:37.814133 - Connecting to database hozana_data...
2021-06-29 10:59:37.822142 - Connecting to archive database hozana_archive...
2021-06-29 10:59:38.046134 - Start ETL main process
2021-06-29 10:59:38.046134 - `users` table:
2021-06-29 10:59:38.046134 - Hashing column `users`.`email:` done.
2021-06-29 10:59:38.054091 - Hashing column `users`.`email_notification:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\anonymization.py", line 17, in hash_column
    c.execute("""
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 183, in execute
    while self.nextset():
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 137, in nextset
    nr = db.next_result()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\main.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\main.py", line 24, in main
    anonymization.main()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\anonymization.py", line 59, in main
    hash_column('users', 'email_notification', 'user_id', True)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\anonymization.py", line 50, in hash_column
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in __exit__
    self.close()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')
```

I thought it was when the client cannot send a query to the server, most likely because the server itself has closed the connection. However I thought there was already a connection:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Even more there are also these lines at the beginning:

```
2021-06-29 10:59:37.814133 - Connecting to database hozana_data...
2021-06-29 10:59:37.822142 - Connecting to archive database hozana_archive...
```

So when I get a `MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')` when closing a SQL query. Is it because of the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour mon amie!

I think you forgot to include `c.close()`

I know I'm 8 months late but guess would suffice other people with the error

I think you must have assigned `c=mysql.connection.cursor()` to establish the code c.execute. I ran into the similar error and I solved by adding `c.close()`